# Hide Dropdown element having common class Jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdowns and i want the second dropdown to hide/show certain elements (having a class) when `$('#first_dropdown').change()` occurs

I tried the same , but with little success, how can i achieve the same , im looking to hide a chunk of `<option>` in my second dropdown how can i do this ?

My tried code :

```
var a = $('#first_dd').val(); //first dropdown - dd value
$('#first_dd').change(function(){
$('.a').hide();        //iv given a class to all elements of second dropdown
});
```

Comment: what is your little success? will you share it with us..

Comment: A jsFiddle would help greatly here!

Comment: @JoeFletch umm , if u see the fiddle made by kakarott in the answer its preciesely what i want , but Jeroen Moons raised a concern that it will not be supported on all browsers

Comment: All I am saying is that if the original poster added some jsFiddle from the beginning it would help a bit. I did not want/mean to take away from any of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hide options from a select box in all browsers. You need to store your options in an array and actually remove them from the select element. Probably easier to rebuild the second select element when the first select element changes, leaving out the options you don't want.

Using Kakarott's fiddle as a base, I'd do it like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/58/)

This should work on all browsers.

**UPDATED** the fiddle to show no options if you didn't select anything in select1 yet.

**Final code:**

HTML

```
<select name="select1" id="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>

<select name="items" id="select2">
    <option value="0" class="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1" class="1">Item 2</option>
    <option value="2" class="2">Item 3</option>
    <option value="3" class="2">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
/* Taking an array of all options-2 and save it on select1 */
$("#category").data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
$("#select2").html("");

$("#category").change(function() { 
    var itemClass = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.' + itemClass);
    $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

​
**Update: Extra clarification**

This line:

```
$("#category").data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
```

Selects the first select box, and using the `.data` method it attaches some data to that select box. **Which data?** All the options that select box 2 contains. **How?** By selecting all options select box 2 contains, and cloning them (copying them).

It saves that set of options because that way we can use this collection again and again, filtering it using the selected value from select box 1 and setting the remaining options as the content of select box 2, replacing whatever options were there before. That happens in this line:

```
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.' + itemClass);
```

So we don't have to hide any options, we just *replace* them every time with the filtered set of all available options.

Comment: Labels change the text of the option, not what you want. I used his fiddle and changed it, this way it should work as you want on all browsers.

Comment: @Jeroen Moons : Good one sir. +1 :)

Comment: @JeroenMoons will try it out and get back in a moment

Comment: @user1537158 I updated the example a bit, now it doesn't show any options in select2 if you didn't select anything in select1 yet. Cleaned up the example a little too.

Comment: umm @JeroenMoons i really need both the dropdowns to be populated at the start , i have already done that using php, also the thing is not working for me , i know ur fiddle runs like a charm but when i select a value from 1st dd , the second one becomes empty ie no values to be shown

Comment: You can leave the part where I remove all the options (`$("#select2").html("");`) out then ;)

Comment: @JeroenMoons can you v briefly tell me what $("#category").data('options',$('#select2 option').clone()); does exactly , please ?

Answer (score 3):

So you are trying to change the second drop down menus according to change on first one.

This fiddle can help you :

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/2/)

Comment: nice fiddle but the new concern is where is it supported on all browsers , thanks alot nonetheless

Comment: @kakarott +1 Great idea cloning the options into data!

Comment: @kakarott can u tell me what $("#category").data('options',$('#select2 option').clone()); does ? pleasse .. ?